# Is anybody able to unaccept answers except the owner of the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

I noticed one thing a few times, after I edited my accepted answer after some time this answer is unmarked as accepted. In my experience, the user who asked the question is not even online in this time, and there's no reason for unaccepting the answer. When I edited my answers, it's in most cases grammar or better code formatting.

Comment: No, only the author of the question can accept/unaccept your answer.

Comment: An answer can be "unaccepted" if it gets deleted. Though I think it retains its "accepted" status so that it's accepted again if it's undeleted. Unless of course the OP accepts a different answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the author of the question can accept/unaccept your answer:

> - You may select any answer *on questions you asked* as the "accepted" answer. Only one answer at a time can be the 'accepted' answer.
>     ...
> - You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

(from the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/295232), emphasis mine)

You can check if the author of the question has been online by looking at their profile, the block at the right contains a 'last seen' line:

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to celebrate next day for very round number of "visited" days :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov wait, I don't get it. In which base you're using is 92 a nice, round number? :P

Comment: Isn't 1024 the best ever round number ? :)